# Can anyone identify what type of bug this is?

Tags: species-identification

Can anyone identify what type of bug this is?

[image]

Comment: Hi, @Correo. Can you tell us where this bug was found please?

Answer (score 2):

From a rummage around Google images for "black and red striped bugs", your insect looks a bit like:

1. *Mylabris syriaca*

[image: Mylabris syriaca]

2. *Hycleus ornatus*, although yours has different antennae.

[image: Hycleus ornatus]

Comment: The antennae do not match Hycleus, and it is definitely not Pyrrhocoris (Hemiptera). It does look like a blister beetle, as is Mylabris.

Comment: looks like Mylabris syriaca to me..

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a wild guess and say that this is *Mylabris quadripunctata*[image]